# Get trayicon tooltip

Tags: windows, tooltip, systray

When you hover over a trayicon in windows, sometimes a tooltip appears giving you some information about the status of the application the trayicon belongs to. I want to get this text into a variable in a programming language (preferebly Batch, AutoIt or python). Is there an easy way? Maybe an executable or a call I don't yet know?

*How* the icon is identified does not really matter for me: could be by process-id, process-name or position in the systray. Even a full list of all tooltips whould be feasible (then I could apply a RegEx to every tooltip, to get the right one).

**Motivation:** that some application (for example Google Drive or Dropbox) communicate their sync status over the tooltip and I want to react to a change of this tooltip by some action (like sending an email, when the status is "Sync completed").

Thank you very much in advance!